# How to change Razor CheckboxFor alignment

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

The standard ASP.NET MVC template in Visual Studio 2013 generates a page `Register.cshtml` that defines the UI for registering new user into the system. I extended it to add a checkbox for "I accept the terms." Here is the code snippet:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.AcceptTerms, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.Label("I accept", new { @class = "control-label" })
    </div>
</div>
```

The idea is that a chexkbox gets displayed below the password editbox. The text must get displayed on the right side of the checkbox.

Here is the partial image of how the output looks:

[image: Partial image]

As you can see, the checkbox is getting center-aligned and "I accept" is flowing to the next line.

How can I keep the checkbox and the label together and also ensure that the checkbox is left-aligned with the editbox above it? Regards.

Comment: this is a css question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this...

```
<label>
I accept

@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.AcceptTerms)
</label>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this ... hope this will help

```
<div class="checkbox">
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IsMobileView, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control pull-left" } })
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that 'label' or/and `input type="checkbox"` have the display type `block`.

To fast check try add `style="display: inline-block"` to both `Label` and `CheckBoxFor`. If I'm right, then you can correct your .css-files.